NFS v4.2 tuning
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JXASmxGrHvY
at 5:30 the statement is made

if you get NFS tuned just right it is incredibly fast for ultra small file transfers*...

at 6:05

I've heard of 4.0GB/sec using a sequential read... but you have to have all the infrastructure tuned just right.

What, where, and how do I tune NFS v4.2 in RHEL-8.10 or later to achieve what is claimed above?   Is this claim true, which this youtube vid seems to be made 3 years ago?
Is there any good NFS tuning documentation as it pertains to NFS v4.2 in RHEL 8/9 or equivalent today?
v4.2 is the latest of NFS correct?  Is there any proposed newer version of NFS on the horizon?
are there any better settings than the default in /etc/nfs.conf and /etc/nfsmount.conf ?
if I can place a bounty on this I will -->  what is the max transfer speed in GB/sec that should be had, in RHEL-8.10 or later, over 100gbps infiniband, on NFS v4.2 (assuming RDMA?) and all the "tuned" options ?? The only tuning I am aware of is putting rdma into effect over infiniband; if someone else knows better/more let me know.


I've heard of 4.0GB/sec using a sequential read... but you have to have all the infrastructure tuned just right.

The author of that video relies on unsourced hearsay. So, disregard any of their claims. Unless they have any experience building such a system.
Their breathless "which is absolutely insane, but the thing is, you gotta have all the infrastructure right" is basically them just being open about being clueless. This is like if you saw me gushing about that I heard that you can cook a really tasty, juicy Christmas dinner for six people in 20 minutes, but you need to get all your kitchen set up correctly. Maybe that's true, maybe it isn't, but it would be pretty clear that I'm not a cook.
What's insane about pushing 4 GB/s through a wire? Sure, you need a storage system that can read that fast, but especially with things already buffered by the block device layer, this doesn't seem to be extreme. Sure, you need some network that can do 32 Gb/s, but with storage attached networking typically being QSFP+28 / 100 Gb/s (and we're not talking about your home computer if we're talking about , hm, that sounds exactly what these devices are made for producing.

What, where, and how do I tune NFS v4.2 in RHEL-8.10 or later to achieve what is claimed above? Is this claim true, which this youtube vid seems to be made 3 years ago?

Do you have a > 40 Gb/s NIC? Do you have storage that fast enough? If not, there's not software tuning that could help you.
If you have, you'd start in default configuration, then identify bottlenecks, then remove them. Obviously, if there was a single way to make your system fast with no downsides, then the default setting would be that.
So, no universal recipe. Just actually understanding what your hard- and software are busy with, and then optimization based on actual profiling.
Chances are you'll want optimized hardware for that. Integration into storage systems is one of the ways companies like Mellanox (now: nvidia) sell their network cards. All in all, I think you're approaching this in a "what configuration file entries should I change" expectation, where in reality it's probably much more architecturally, for example, "which kind of multipath storage server array should I buy, and how do I architect the network to the clients for this to be possible?".

v4.2 is the latest of NFS correct?

yes. But note that there's optional features, and no single NFS implementation will have all of them.

Is there any proposed newer version of NFS on the horizon?

Yes, NFS is still an evolving protocol, with datacenter-grade optimizations (better RoCE/RDMA integration, better caching, better coherency all around, queues, security, packet loss handling, multipath support…) are things that equipment companies and operators are pushing for. I'm not pertinent to bleeding-edge developments of NFS, but to someone on an old RHEL, that's irrelevant anyways. You'd start by upgrading to a modern system before wondering whether any future standard is of relevance to your performance.

I have dell r700's series servers having mellanox 100gbps nic, at most I have gotten 1.0 GB/sec as shown via scp over SSH between two servers on an infiniband LAN with NFS v.2 rdma doing a single 10gb tar file with a default /etc/nfs.conf file in rhel-8.10.  I have posted here about it.  My experience has been NFS is horrible when there are many small files such as a cp -r folder containing thousands+ of < ~10mb files (contrary to this youtube claim)

and my copy, for testing, is with servers having 512gb or 768gb ram, so taking disk out of the equation and relying on RAM (disk caching).  My typical speeds are 400mb/sec and 700 mb/sec for single large files; 112 MB/sec over 1gbps.

from my typically observed 112 MB/sec via scp or samba to windows 10/11 over 1gbps copper why should I not expect a 112 * 100 = 11,200 MB/sec or 11.2 GB/sec when the physical network goes from 1gps to 100gbps infiniband?   ...just give me the 4.0GB/sec like was claimed by mr. youtube guy and i'll be happy

@ron it's good that you just added that information to your question, it should honestly been have there from the beginnings.

@ron note that the guy doesn't claim he could do 4GB/s with small files, but with linear read, so the opposite.

@ron "should I not expect" (scaling of NFS throughput with scaling of network interconnect): No. that's literally what my answer says: The thing bottlenecking your transfer speed will be something different on different systems. You need to actually profile your very system to figure what bottlenecks. For example: can your storage keep up with your network card? Can your interrupt load? Can your memory bandwidth? Your PCIe?

With enough ram cache at the client end and the server end, astonishingly fast speeds for small sets of data can be  achieved.  But this is more a lab test result than a practical result in the real world.  I'm not objecting to anything you wrote @MarcusMüller I'm just adding a comment about the OP's belief in the claims made by a blogger/vlogger.  They could be completely true, but mostly useless.
